# Customizing percentile calculation in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

#### Overview

Given the following T-SQL Query, is it possible to use
`PERCENT_RANK` or a similar function do get the desired percentile? If not, what is the simplest way to accomplish this goal?

```sql
SELECT rank, 
ROUND(
    100 * PERCENT_RANK() 
    OVER (ORDER BY rank DESC), 
2) as pctile,
desired_pctile

FROM ( VALUES (1, 100), (1, 100), (1, 100), (2, 62.5), (3, 50), (3, 50), (4, 25), (5, 12.5) ) as X(rank, desired_pctile)
```

| rank | pctile | desired_pctile |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 0 | 12.5 |
| 4 | 14.29 | 25 |
| 3 | 28.57 | 50 |
| 3 | 28.57 | 50 |
| 2 | 57.14 | 62.5 |
| 1 | 71.43 | 100 |
| 1 | 71.43 | 100 |
| 1 | 71.43 | 100 |

#### Details

Specifically, the pctile and desired_pctile calculations are defined slightly differently.

- pctile: the percentage of **other** records with a rank less than the current record's rank.
- desired_pctile: the percentage of records with a rank less than or equal to the current record's rank.

This means that there are two distinctions:

1. When multiple records share the same rank, the desired behavior is to take the maximum instead of the minimum (see Python for an example).
2. The denominator is N-1, where having N is desired. Where N is the record count. Is there a way to multiply pctile by `COUNT(*) / (COUNT(*)-1)` in the query?

#### Python Equivalent

In pandas the [rank function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html) has a parameter `method` for specifying how to handle multiple records that share the same value. The following python code obtains the desired result:

```python
pd.Series([1,1,1,2,3,3,4,5]).rank(method='max', ascending=False, pct=True)
```

Comment: why not build your own function as you can't modify definition of percentile

Comment: Something like `(COUNT() - RANK() + 1) / COUNT()`, but defined using window functions. The non-dense `RANK()` should yield values 1, 1, 1, 4, 5, 5, 7, 8.

Comment: Seems like the best solution is to build a custom function. I just wanted to check for a simpler solution first. Thank you @T N for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that calculates a windowed form of `1 - (rank() - 1) / count()`, scaled and rounded to percentages. This is a slight improvement over what I originally posted in my comment, as it eliminates the duplicate count subexpression.

```
SELECT
    rank,
    ROUND(100 - 100.0 * (RANK() OVER (ORDER BY rank) - 1)
                      / (COUNT(*) OVER())
        , 2) as pctile, 
    desired_pctile
FROM (
    VALUES
        (1, 100), (1, 100), (1, 100), (2, 62.5),
        (3, 50), (3, 50), (4, 25), (5, 12.5)
) as X(rank, desired_pctile)
```

Results:

| rank | pctile | desired_pctile |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100.000000000000 | 100.0 |
| 1 | 100.000000000000 | 100.0 |
| 1 | 100.000000000000 | 100.0 |
| 2 | 62.500000000000 | 62.5 |
| 3 | 50.000000000000 | 50.0 |
| 3 | 50.000000000000 | 50.0 |
| 4 | 25.000000000000 | 25.0 |
| 5 | 12.500000000000 | 12.5 |

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/q6iRVPhm).